# How do I properly replace identifiers with variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess I am to stupid to get this to work.

I have a shoppingcart which can be splitted in multiple carts, if someone buys items from different sellers. 
So I create for every seller his own form and table, which IDs are extended by $sellerId.
Next step is to count how much elements with class 'delete16' are in the given table, for example with id="cartTable_815".

I can get this to work if I code this:

```
var n = $("#cartTable_815 div[class=delete16]").length;
```

But if I want to write myself a function to count the elements with class 'delete16' within a variable table-id I tried this:

```
    $("#cartInner div[class=delete16]").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    removeItem(id);
    });

    function removeItem(id)
    {
       var identifiers = id.split("_"); 
       var cartId = identifiers[1];
       var itemId = identifiers[2];
       var tab = "cartTable_" + cartId;
       var n = $("#cartTable_815 div[class=delete16]").length;
       alert(n);
    }
```

If I replace #cartTable_815 with tab it does not work.

```
var n = $("#cartTable_" + tab + "div[class=delete16]").length;
```

Hope someone can explain me how I have to do this the right way.

Thanks for your time and reading

Comment: you are missing a space `var n = $("#cartTable_" + tab + " div[class=delete16]").length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `tab` already contains a number, it probably has the value `cartTable_815`. So, you should be able to do:

```
var n = $("#" + tab + " div[class=delete16]").length;
```

And the selector will be:

```
// "#" + tab  +  " div[class=delete16]"
   "#cartTable_815 div[class=delete16]"
```

Comment: Oh my god... of course. I should go to bed now... thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll do so - still have to wait 2 minutes :-) Kind regards from Spain